# parentheses vs brackets for indexed family of sets

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the definition of parentheses and brackets. However this problem involving indexed family of sets has me questioning the definitions.

Q: Let $\mathscr A = \{[-x,0]: x \in \mathbb R \text{ and } 0 < x < 1\}$.
Find the union over $\mathscr A$ and the intersection over $\mathscr A.$

A:  (The union over $\mathscr A$) $= [-1,0]$.
(The intersection over $\mathscr A$) $= \{0\}$.

So, I am confused how the set is defined with $[-x,0]$, and $x$ is restricted by $0 < x < 1$. So, would (the union of $\mathscr A$) $= (-1,0]$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you means $x$ is _in_ the set of all real numbers rather than $x$ _is_ the set of all real numbers. $\qquad$

Comment: . . . . . and now I've taken the liberty of changing it so that it says $x\in\mathbb R$. $\qquad$

Comment: yes thank you!!

Comment: That's what I meant, thank you for clarifying and editing!

Answer (score -1):

$(-1,0]$ is correct.

The number $-1$ is not an element of any set in the family $\mathcal{A}$ and therefore cannot be in the union.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I read it as -1 not an element of any set as well but the brackets screwed me up.